Как отловить событие входа нового пользователя в группе телеграм
Может кто подсказать как отловить заход в группу новых пользователей которые впоследствии потом спамят,
Не new_chat_member не new_chat_members не устаревший new_chat_participant не видят входа этих пользователей(ботов) в группу,
Даже весь апдейт который приходит с телеги через Webhook или Long Polling в нем нет этих ботов, хотя в десктопной версии телеги в недавних действиях видно этих юзеров что они вступили в группу
Как вообще такое возможно
Права у бота есть все, эти спамеры в основном имеют премиум аккаунты
Ну вот очередной спам, через управление группой видно, что она вступила, а в самом чате группы НЕТ, записи о ее вступлении, как такое возможно вообще, и какие способы отлова можно применить еще?



У ботов в группах очень урезанные права, они там только команды видят да и всё, можете дать ему админку и с ней проверить

Права у бота все, других то новых пользователей он видит, а именно этих спамеров нет, они в основном все с премиум аккаунтом, чтобы их телега быстро не банила
